# Minikube mount process stops unexpectedly sometimes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have started a minikube mount process using the following command and it stops unexpectedly. How can I make it running all the time?

`minikube mount "$HOME/data:/home2" --ip 10.0.11.1 >/dev/null &`

I have to run it again whenever I notice it stopped.

Comment: To make the minikube mount process run continuously, you can use a tool called [nohup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nohup-command-in-linux) along with the & symbol. Can you try this command : `nohup minikube mount "$HOME/data:/home2" --ip 10.0.11.1 \>/dev/null 2\>&1 &`

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: @Lejidi prifti : Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.